# How to get the Single String value from the Multiple checkbox which are only checked

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm using spinner to get selected value and upload it on firebase database. since from drop down only one value can be selected, so there is another Editbox where individual can write if they have elligible for other option too and it is totally a lengthy process.

So I'm looking to implement multiple check box in Grid view such that when user check the given check box, then I could retrive only the value that are checked in one single string and later upload in firebase.

Here is the code I found

```html
public class MainActivity_test extends Activity {



    CheckBox chk1,chk2,chk3,chk4,chk5,chk6,chk7,chk8,chk9;
    Button btn;

    TextView txt;
    ArrayList<String> list ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


        list = new ArrayList<String>();


        chk1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);  
        chk2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);  
        chk3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);  
        chk4=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);  
        chk5=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);  
        chk6=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);  
        chk7=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);  
        chk8=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox8);  
        chk9=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox9);  
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {


        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                for (String str : list) {
     txt.setText(txt.getText().toString() + " , " + str);
}


            }

        });

    }



    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox1:
             list.add(chk1.getTag().toString());


        break;
        case R.id.checkBox2:
            list.add(chk2.getTag().toString());

        break;

        case R.id.checkBox3:
            list.add(chk3.getTag().toString());

            break;
        case R.id.checkBox4:
            list.add(chk4.getTag().toString());

            break;
        case R.id.checkBox5:
            list.add(chk5.getTag().toString());

            break;
        case R.id.checkBox6:
            list.add(chk6.getTag().toString());

            break;
        case R.id.checkBox7:
            list.add(chk7.getTag().toString());

            break;
        case R.id.checkBox8:
            list.add(chk8.getTag().toString());

            break;
        case R.id.checkBox9:
            list.add(chk9.getTag().toString());

            break;

        }
        }


}
```

But How do I get the value of only Selected item in as One single String output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just make a for loop that check every checkbox if its checked, if it is add the value to the String.

Comment: and the question is how...!!

Comment: @AgonAvdijaj can you please show me how can I do that?

Comment: You could just add all your various checkboxes to an array or list. Stream the array. Lets call that collection or array `x` and assume it's an array. `Arrays.stream(x).filter(x -> x.isSelected()).map(this::**function that takes a checkbox and returns some text);`

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
public class MainActivity_test extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    addCheckboxListner();
}

private void addCheckboxListner(){
    chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    chk2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    chk3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    chk4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    chk5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    chk6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    chk7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    chk8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    chk9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    onCheckboxClicked(buttonView);
}}
```

Comment: but where is the string here?

Comment: i suggest to build a Map the key will be the check box id and the value is the String you want

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't do this..searched for  online...but to my surprise found no any tutorial or any thing for an newcomer like me...so sad